# Search text file and display results in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, search, file-io, jtextpane

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can search a text file and list the results in a JComponent, like a JPanel.

I've been trying to make this work out for two days now, but no success will really appreciate a reply. Thanks a lot in advance.

I've been trying to write a class that handles search queries to a text file. My main goal is to get the lines in a text file that contain the search keywords entered in a JTextField and print them out in an appropriate JComponent(something like a JTextField, JTextPane, whichever best applicable).

I'd like the search results to show in columns like how google search results get displayed, so that each line from the text file gets printed in its own line. I've been told that it's best to use an ArrayList. I really don't know how to do this. I've picked up ideas from all over and this is what I have so far:

Much appreciation in advance. I am very new to Java. I've been at it the whole day trying to get this right and have not gone any far. Am willing to try anything offered, even a new approach.

```
// The class that handles the search query
// Notice that I've commented out some parts that show errors

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;


public class Search {

    public static String path;
    public static String qri;

    public Search(String dTestFileDAT, String qry) {
        path = dTestFileDAT;
        qri = qry;
    }

    public static JTextPane resultJTextPane;
    public static List<String> linesToPresent = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static List<String> searchFile(String path, String match){

        File f = new File(path);
        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
                do{
                    line = br.readLine();
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(match);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                    if(m.find())
                        linesToPresent.add(line);
                } while(line != null);

                br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // resultJTextPane = new JTextPane();
        // resultJTextPane = (JTextPane) Home.BulletinsJPanel.add(linesToPresent);

        return linesToPresent;
    }
}

// This handles the click event to take the query. Notice that I've commented out some parts that show errors
private void mouseClickedSearch(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Search fs = new Search("/D:/TestFile.dat/", "Text to search for");

    // searchResultsJPanel.add(Search.searchFile("/D:/TestFile.dat/", "COLE"));
    // searchResultsJTextField.add(fs);
}
```

Comment: *"Does anyone have any ideas on how I can search a text file and list the results in a JComponent, like a JPanel?*" - Yes - [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Maybe we can give some direction

Comment: You've been trying to make this work for two days, so surely you have some code you can show us? Some starting point? Let's see it.

Comment: @olicver muchai see JTextPane.read()

Comment: +1 for showing us some code :)

Comment: Maybe like this? https://github.com/qwerky/File-Search/tree/master/src/qwerky/tools/filesearch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions, this is just a simple one (no seriously, it is ;))

Basically, this just uses a `JList` to store all the matches of the search text from the search file.

This is a case sensitive search, so beware

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MySearch();
    }

    public MySearch() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField findText;
        private JButton search;
        private DefaultListModel<String> model;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            findText = new JTextField(20);
            searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            search = new JButton("Search");
            searchPane.add(search, gbc);

            add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            JList list = new JList(model);
            add(new JScrollPane(list));

            ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

            search.addActionListener(handler);
            findText.addActionListener(handler);
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.removeAllElements();
//                    BufferedReader reader = null;

                String searchText = findText.getText();
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("search.txt")))) {

                    String text = null;
                    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (text.contains(searchText)) {

                            model.addElement(text);

                        }

                    }

                } catch (IOException exp) {

                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Could not create file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also take another tact and simply highlight the matches...

[image]

This uses a slightly different approach as this is interactive.  Basically you simply type, wait a 1/4 second and it will start searching...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class MySearch02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MySearch02();
    }

    public MySearch02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField findText;
        private JTextArea ta;
        private Timer keyTimer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            findText = new JTextField(20);
            searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

            add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            loadFile();

            keyTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String find = findText.getText();
                    Document document = ta.getDocument();
                    try {
                        for (int index = 0; index + find.length() < document.getLength(); index++) {
                            String match = document.getText(index, find.length());
                            if (find.equals(match)) {
                                javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter =
                                        new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
                                ta.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, index + find.length(),
                                        highlightPainter);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (BadLocationException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            keyTimer.setRepeats(false);

            findText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    keyTimer.restart();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    keyTimer.restart();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    keyTimer.restart();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void loadFile() {
            String searchText = findText.getText();
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("search.txt")))) {
                ta.read(reader, "Text");
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Could not create file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            ta.setCaretPosition(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel You'd think I was boarder or something ;)

Comment: :-) you were boarder or something, phaaaa not I haven't problem to call the things with its proper names

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SearchTextFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SearchTextFile();
}

public SearchTextFile() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bible Search");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField findText;
    private JButton search;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;
    private JList list;

    private String searchPhrase;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        findText = new JTextField(20);
        searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        search = new JButton("Search");
        searchPane.add(search, gbc);

        add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        list = new JList(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new HighlightListCellRenderer());
        add(new JScrollPane(list));

        ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

        search.addActionListener(handler);
        findText.addActionListener(handler);

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Script.txt")))) {

            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                model.addElement(text);
            }

        } catch (IOException exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            searchPhrase = findText.getText();
            if (searchPhrase != null && searchPhrase.trim().length() == 0) {
                searchPhrase = null;
            }
            list.repaint();
//              model.removeAllElements();
////                    BufferedReader reader = null;
//
//              String searchText = findText.getText();
//              try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("bible.txt")))) {
//
//                  String text = null;
//                  while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//
//                      if (text.contains(searchText)) {
//
//                          model.addElement(text);
//
//                      }
//
//                  }
//
//              } catch (IOException exp) {
//
//                  exp.printStackTrace();
//                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Something Went     Wrong", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
//
//              }
        }
    }

        public class HighlightListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        public final String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value instanceof String && searchPhrase != null) {
                String text = (String) value;
                if (text.contains(searchPhrase)) {
                    text = text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
                    value = "<html>" + text.replace(searchPhrase, "<font color=#ffff00>" + searchPhrase + "</font>") + "</html>";
                }
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

    }
}
}
```